# Spring: get bean based on parameters

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I have a bean factory class as follows:

```
public class BeanFactory {
public static BeanInterface getInstance(int id) {
    return new Bean(id);
    }
}
```

I want to use this class in spring container to get the instances of Instrument class, and  have added a bean entry in `applicationcontext.xml` as follows:

```
<bean id="TestBean" class="com.test.beans.BeanFactory" factory-method="getInstance">
</bean>
```

But I am not able to find any way through which I can pass id to `getInstance` factory method.
Is there any way I can pass a parameter to this factory method?

**EDIT:** Consider the bean factory as scope="prototype". I want new instances of `TestBean` based on the value of ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules are the same as if it was normal Spring constructor, i.e. you can use `<contructor-arg value="..."/>`

From [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html)

> Arguments to the static factory method are supplied via
>    elements, exactly the same as if a constructor had
>   actually been used. The type of the class being returned by the
>   factory method does not have to be of the same type as the class that
>   contains the static factory method, although in this example it is. An
>   instance (non-static) factory method would be used in an essentially
>   identical fashion (aside from the use of the factory-bean attribute
>   instead of the class attribute), so details will not be discussed
>   here.

Answer (score 1):

The complete solution is :

Bean Entry:

```
<bean id="TestBean"  class="com.test.beans.BeanFactory" factory-method="getInstance" abstract="false" singleton="false" >
</bean>
```

Getting bean in code:

```
TestBeanInterface visitingLocation = (TestBeanInterface)    ctx.getBean("TestBean",42); //passing the argument for static method
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters to factory methods using `<constructor-arg>` element:

```
<bean id="TestBean" class="com.test.beans.BeanFactory" factory-method="getInstance">
    <constructor-arg value = "42" />
</bean>
```

Comment: ok. But I want this value to be dynamic, like  passing different values of the Id based on user input. is there any way i can pass this id through code at the runtime.

Comment: @Manish: If so, are you sure you want to declare `BeanInterface` as a bean? You can declare `BeanFactory` as a bean, inject it into your classes and call `getInstance()` when you want.

Comment: yes, agreed and I think that is the better way. But I wanted to get the bean directly, without explicitly calling getInstance() from code.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a class instance (another bean) as a parameter.

```
<bean id="TestBean" class="com.test.beans.BeanFactory" factory-method="getInstance">
    <property name="beanBuilder" ref="BeanBuilder"/>
</bean>

<bean id="BeanBuilder" class="com.test.beans.SelectedBeanBuilder"/>
```